Syncing Excel cells with Word table cells on SharePoint - Possible?
I have some Microsoft Office files on SharePoint:

An Excel file (.xlsm)
A Word document (.docx)

I want to create a table in the Word doc and have a block of its cells automatically sync with a specific block of cells in the Excel file. Is this doable? If so, how?
Ideally, when I update the Excel file, the Word doc should reflect those changes without manual copying and pasting.
I know how to embed a block of cells from Excel into Word (Home > Paste > Paste Special > Paste Link > Microsoft Excel Worksheet (code) Object), but this is not what I need. I need a native Word table so I can add columns, which do not exist in the Excel file.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. Following the request in the first comment here some clarification:

The minimum requirement is that the Word document fetch the latest updates from the Excel file on SharePoint upon opening.
I like the idea of using Power Apps, however, I have had quite some issues with licensing in my company. So Office Scripts are also a viable option.


Please edit/update your question with additional context as there may be lots of ways to do this. For instance do you want to push data from excel (on update) to word, or do you want word to pull data (on start) from excel, or do you want to do this update on regular intervals? Since you state sharepoint, it seems like your options are officescript or powerapps. Good luck.

@gns100 these are very good points that I was not aware of. Thanks a lot. I added a P.S. for clarification. Power Apps seems like a very interesting option but I have had quite some issues with requesting different functionalities and licensing in my company.

Doing a bit of research it seems Power Automate (formerly Microsoft Flow) is also a nice option to look into.
